# Can I run xvfb on a console-only debian system?

Tags: debian, console, livecd, xvfb

I need to be able to run firefox on a console-only debian system, and I want to run it using xvfb.

The command I have been using to run it on my regular debian system is:

```
$ xvfb-run firefox &
```

But on my livecd, after running this command it exits almost immediately and I don't see xvfb running when I do:

```
$ ps -ef | grep -i 'xvfb'
```

Are there some special packages I need to include on my livecd other than gtk2.0-0, atk1.0-0 and xvfb?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the -e flag to xvfb-run so you can see what is going wrong:

```
xvfb-run -e /tmp/xvfb-errors.txt firefox &
```

Now this may show you some error messages:

```
cat /tmp/xvfb-errors.txt
```